# Infinite loop when using react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

I am new to React hooks and have been experimenting with them. I am trying to write a usePostForm hook, where I can copy the post-state and merge it with the new post field but for some reason, I keep getting an infinite loop. What am I missing?

```
const usePostForm = field => {
  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    title: '',
    points: '',
    course: '',
    question: ''
  });

  const setFormPost = () => {
    setPost({ ...post, ...field });
  };
  return [post, setFormPost];
};
```

Later in another function, I am calling it as

```
const [post,setPost]=usePostForm()
setPost({title:'hello'})
```

Comment: Try creating a better example, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it highly depends on **where** you call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you're invoking the `setPost` is key. In the example above, every time the component rerenders it invokes the `setPost` over and over.

The easiest approach would be to set values from within a `form`. If you're using form elements, you can use `event.target` to update the values in a `useCallback` function. For example, using the `useCallback` function in combination with the `prevState` callback:

```
const usePostForm = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    title: '',
    points: '',
    course: '',
    question: ''
  });

  const setFormPost = React.useCallback(
    ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
      setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value })),
    [setValues]
  );

  return [values, setFormPost];
};
```

Where `name` and `value` are coming from `event.target`:

```
<input type="text" name="title" value={values.title} onChange={setFormPost} />
```

I found this to be the easiest way to utilize a single object state with multiple properties. Then you can either add `field` in `handleSubmit` (if it doen't need to be controlled) or add `field` to your initial `useState` call (if it needs to be applied to a field as an initial value).

For example, this initializes values via the `spread syntax` within the `useState` function (click the `run code snippet` button below):

```js
const usePostForm = field => {
  const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    title: '',
    points: '',
    course: '',
    question: '',
    ...field
  });

  const setFormPost = React.useCallback(
    ({ target: { name, value } }) =>
      setValues(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value })),
    [setValues]
  );

  return [values, setFormPost];
};

const Form = () => {
  const [values, setFormPost] = usePostForm({ 
    title: "Initial Title Value", 
    points: 1 
  });
  
 const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 4));
  };
   
    return(
      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <p className="label">Title:</p>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            name="title"
            placeholder=""
            value={values.title}
            onChange={setFormPost}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <p className="label">Points:</p>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="number"
            name="points"
            placeholder=""
            value={values.points}
            onChange={setFormPost}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <p className="label">Course:</p>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            name="course"
            placeholder=""
            value={values.course}
            onChange={setFormPost}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="input-container">
          <p className="label">Question:</p>
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            name="question"
            placeholder=""
            value={values.question}
            onChange={setFormPost}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="btn-container">
          <button className="btn primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: .875rem;
  line-height: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: .1s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: color,background-color,border-color;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.form {
  width: 550px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.danger {
  background-color: #f0506e;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
 
.danger:hover {
  background-color: #ee395b;
  color: #fff;
}

.error {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -20px;
  padding-left: 26%;
  color: red;
  text-align: left;
}

.input {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #666;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: color,background-color,border;
 }
 
.input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #1e87f0;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.input-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.label {
  width: 25%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 34px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}

.primary {
  background-color: #1e87f0;
}

.primary:hover {
  background-color: #0f7ae5;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take note that you are missing an argument at `setFormPost`:

```
const setFormPost = field => {
  setPost({ ...post, ...field });
};
```

The infinite loop depends on where/which context you calling `setFormPost` (you should elaborate more), my guess it's in `useEffect` which causes a render loop.